# How to do multiple table view in scroll view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to IOS, I want three table views in one view controller. when I scroll in horizontal it will move to table 2 and table 3. please help me in coding. how doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Put horizontal scroll view with content offset width equal to 3 tables width then add uitableviews to that scroll view with proper x origin. Obviously it would be better to use NSLayoutConstraints for that, but the first way is o.k. for you I guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784325/horizontal-uiscrollview-with-multiple-uitableviews

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720733/with-multiple-uitableviews-in-a-single-uiscrollview-how-to-only-load-cell-data